# Getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/day/cq/commons/Filter

Tags: aem, apache-felix, sling, aem-6

Getting the below error message when we are accessing any page in our site even though the bundle is in active state:
**org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException:    javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/day/cq/commons/Filter**

Day Communique 5 Commons Library bundle in felix console:
[image: Day Communique 5 Commons Library bundle in felix console]

Version of AEM: 6.1

Comment: Which bundle are you referring to as active? can you paste the whole output from the bundle's /system/console/bundles/### page?

Comment: it is Day Communique 5 Commons Library bundle. added screenshot

Comment: Did you try restarting AEM instance to see if class gets loaded correctly?

Comment: the information you provide is not clear, can you explain more about your problem ?